# Reading from serial port using Arduino giving garbage output

Tags: multithreading, go, serial-port

I'm currently trying to read input from the serial port through an Arduino using multithreading. I have two threads reading from the serial port, and they are both reading the **same thing** (ignore their function names). Here is the code:

```
 func readFirstLine(scanner *bufio.Scanner, port *serial.Port){
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Printf("%q\n", scanner.Text())
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1)*time.Second)
}

func readSecondLine(scanner *bufio.Scanner, port *serial.Port){
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1)*time.Second)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Printf("%q\n", scanner.Text())
    }
}

func main() {
    usbRead := &serial.Config{Name: "COM5", Baud: 9600, ReadTimeout: 0}
    port, err := serial.OpenPort(usbRead)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(port)

    for true {
        go readFirstLine(scanner, port)
        go readSecondLine(scanner, port)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(2)*time.Second)
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output to look like this:

```
{"temperature":[26,26],"humidity":[54.2,54.2],"sensor":"DHT22"}
{"temperature":[23.46041,23.46041],"sensor":"LM35DZ"}
{"blink":["true","true"],"actuator":"arduinoLED"}
{"temperature":[26,26],"humidity":[54.2,54.2],"sensor":"DHT22"}
{"temperature":[23.46041,23.46041],"sensor":"LM35DZ"}
{"blink":["true","true"],"actuator":"arduinoLED"}
```

Yet I am getting garbage output in between the expected output:

```
"{\"temperature\":[23.46041,23.46041,23.46041],\"sensor\":\"LM35DZ\"}"
"{\"blink\":[\"true\",\"true\",\"true\"],\"actuator\":\"arduinoLED\"}"
"mpeer\x00\x00re\"u:\x00\x00[]6\x00midhui\x00\x00[54\":.\x00\x00sen,\"s\x00\x00:or\"\"TH\x00"
{\"}\"\x00\x00ptemurrate\x003.4[26\x00\x00,\"s1]e\x00\x00\":\"orL\x00\x00Z\"}5D\r\x00\x00\x00"
```

I believe this garbage output appears because I am reading serial port input even when the Arduino hasn't outputted anything. Is there any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Note that you're not actually doing multithreading, per se. You're doing concurrency. This can happen the same way in a single thread.

Comment: Note that `for true` is the same as `for`.  That is, you can omit the "true"

Answer (score 1):

You are concurrently reading from and writing to a `bufio.Scanner` with no synchronization mechanism.

Reference: [Introducing the Go Race Detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

Comment: If I were to just use sync.WaitGroup would that be enough? Sorry I'm still fairly new to the language and this is my first time working with both Go and serial ports.